# Extract date format from date string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to extract the generic date format from a string:

source string:
`date_string = "VendorCatalog07-10-2022.csv"`

output string:
`date_format_string = "VendorCatalog%d-%m-%Y.csv"`

is there any datetime method or library that helps me with this?

Comment: The main question is whether you would know at which position the month or day will be ? 

If you do know that all of them will be DDMMYY for example, then you could use Regex's `re.sub` for this.

Otherwise I dont see a viable solution if you dont know where the days or months will be positioned at.

Comment: that example date might as well be "%m-%d-%Y" - how would you determine that?

Comment: i know, it may be ambiguous, it may also be invalid or unrecognized. I could get that as an output, im not argueing with that, i was thinking there must be a solution for this.